# How to handle data newly collected between data dumped and submitted to Odoo for version upgrade conversion

Tags: odoo

Assuming we are using Odoo 12 and would like to upgrade to Odoo 13.

The practise is to submit the database dump in version 12 and then wait until Odoo test and convert to odoo 13 compatible database dump. However it takes days even weeks for Odoo to convert my whole database dump. It is impossible for me to stop my Odoo application in production

My question is how should I handle data newly collected in my Odoo 12 production environment?

Answer (score 1):

Our approach is to submit the database once, then Odoo usually takes a while (but they automate your update in the meantime). Then test the updated DB on our test environment. For the final update take the dump give it to Odoo and if possible stop the odoo server in the meantime (or put it to readonly mode). The final update normally "only" takes a few hours (because it was automated upon the first submission of the database).

Comment: Yes there are two "modes" for the upgrade process. At first submit your database as test upgrade. Odoo will write the upgrade scripts. This step just takes long, because you're not the only one submitting database for migration. Finally submit once again a database for test migration, and if everything went well and fast you can start upgrading/migrating in production mode. Usually it runs in under an hour...